# ldap_simple_bind_s returned LDAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS

Tags: c++, ldap

Our application used LDAP for authentification. When ldap_bind_s is used, it returned LDAP_SUCCES while ldap_simple_bind_s returned LAP_INVALID_CREDENTIALS with wrong credentials. Can you explain the difference and if using ldap_simple_bind_s is secure ?

Here's a sample application using both methods.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
#include <winldap.h>
#include <boost/lexcal_cast.hpp>

using namespace std;

void test_ldap_bind_s(const std::string& hostname, int port, const std::string& username, const std::string& password)
{   
    ULONG version = LDAP_VERSION3;
    ULONG portNumber = port;
    long timeout = 5;

    LDAP* ldap = ldap_init(const_cast<PCHAR>(hostname.c_str()), portNumber);

    ULONG error_code = LdapGetLastError();
    std::string error_str = ldap_err2string(error_code);
    if (0x0 == ldap)
    {
        cout << error_code << ": " << error_str << endl << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "ldap_init -> " << error_str << endl;

    error_code = ldap_set_option(ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, static_cast<void*>(&version));
    error_str = ldap_err2string(error_code);
    if (error_code != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << error_code << ": " << error_str << endl << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "ldap_set_option LDAP_VERSION3 -> " << error_str << endl;

    l_timeval ldap_connect_timeout;
    ldap_connect_timeout.tv_sec = timeout;
    ldap_connect_timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    error_code = ldap_connect(ldap, &ldap_connect_timeout);
    error_str = ldap_err2string(error_code);
    if (error_code != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << error_code << ": " << error_str << endl << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "ldap_connect -> " << error_str << endl;

    SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY secWinntAuthIdentity;
    ZeroMemory(static_cast<void*>(&secWinntAuthIdentity), sizeof(SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY));
    secWinntAuthIdentity.User = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(const_cast<char*>(username.c_str()));
    secWinntAuthIdentity.UserLength = username.length();
    secWinntAuthIdentity.Password = reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(const_cast<char*>(password.c_str()));
    secWinntAuthIdentity.PasswordLength = password.length();
    secWinntAuthIdentity.Domain = 0;
    secWinntAuthIdentity.DomainLength = 0;
    secWinntAuthIdentity.Flags = SEC_WINNT_AUTH_IDENTITY_ANSI;

    error_code = ldap_bind_s(ldap, NULL, reinterpret_cast<char*>(&secWinntAuthIdentity), LDAP_AUTH_NEGOTIATE);
    error_str = ldap_err2string(error_code);
    if (error_code != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << error_code << ": " << error_str << endl << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "ldap_bind_s -> " << error_str << endl << endl;
}

void test_ldap_simple_bind_s(const std::string& hostname, int port, const std::string& username, const std::string& password)
{   
    ULONG version = LDAP_VERSION3;
    ULONG portNumber = port;
    long timeout = 5;

    LDAP* ldap = ldap_init(const_cast<PCHAR>(hostname.c_str()), portNumber);

    ULONG error_code = LdapGetLastError();
    std::string error_str = ldap_err2string(error_code);
    if (0x0 == ldap)
    {
        cout << error_code << ": " << error_str << endl << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "ldap_init -> " << error_str << endl;

    error_code = ldap_set_option(ldap, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, static_cast<void*>(&version));
    error_str = ldap_err2string(error_code);
    if (error_code != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << error_code << ": " << error_str << endl << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "ldap_set_option LDAP_VERSION3 -> " << error_str << endl;

    l_timeval ldap_connect_timeout;
    ldap_connect_timeout.tv_sec = timeout;
    ldap_connect_timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    error_code = ldap_connect(ldap, &ldap_connect_timeout);
    error_str = ldap_err2string(error_code);
    if (error_code != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << error_code << ": " << error_str << endl << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "ldap_connect -> " << error_str << endl;

    error_code = ldap_simple_bind_s(ldap, const_cast<PCHAR>(username.c_str()), const_cast<PCHAR>(password.c_str()));
    error_str = ldap_err2string(error_code);
    if (error_code != LDAP_SUCCESS)
    {
        cout << error_code << ": " << error_str << endl << endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "ldap_bind_s -> " << error_str << endl << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string username = argv[1];
    string password = argv[2];
    string hostname = argv[3];
    int port = boost::lexical_cast<int>(argv[4]);

    test_ldap_bind_s(hostname, port, username, password);
    test_ldap_simple_bind_s(hostname, port, username, password);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ldap_simple_bind_s credentials are not username, password but DN, password.
You would need to retrieve the DN from LDAP, or build it from the username (assuming the DNs are all built identically).